# How to handle accented chars in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I know that there's a lot of material about it, but I can't work out a solution for my problem.

I have this text written in a txt file that I have to manipulate, etc. and it contains lots of accented chars. I can't manage them correctly for some reason. Here's my code:

```
file = open ('parsed.txt', 'w', encoding = 'latin1')
file.write('ààààà')
```

This works fine.

But I need to make this work fine too:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding = 'latin1') as f:
    string = f.read()
    or_array = string.splitlines()
    new_array = []
    for line in or_array:
        new = (line[13:]).strip()
        print(new)
        new_array.append(new)
    new_string = ''
    for lin in new_array:
        new_string += lin
        new_string += ' '
    f_n = open('parsed.txt', 'w', encoding = 'latin1')
    f_n.write(new_string)
```

what is wrong with that code?

input:

```
00:00:06.49    ciaò
00:00:20.665     Questa è una provà
00:00:44.157     èè   aa ò à ùù ù
00:00:44.157
```

output:

```
ciaò Questa è una provàèè   aa ò à ùù ù
```

[image: output]

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me if the content of *input.txt* is actually in ISO-8859-1. If it's in UTF-8 then you get the incorrect results you're seeing. In other words, when I copy/paste your input I get a file whose content are UTF-8. If I do `iconv -f utf-8 -t L1 < utf8.txt > input.txt` then your program works fine.

By the way, your program isn't idiomatic python and is going to be very inefficient on large inputs.

Comment: thank you. yes, the problem was that input.txt was coded in utf-8. I know that this program would be very inefficient on large inputs, the original input.txt was 130 lines long so no problem. BTW I must look for "idiomatic python" because I don't know what is.

Comment: @ZenoDallaValle "Idiomatic" in this context means "typical" or "the usual way". For example, you wouldn't normally do `f.read()`. Instead you would treat it as an iterator to consume one line at a time: `for line in f:`.